# How can I count pairs of matching descendant nodes?

Tags: xpath

I want to count the number of `<C>` nodes that match a certain `<A>` node.

Example tree with desired answer `2`:

```xml
<e>
  <A> txt </A>
  <e>
    <A> txt </A>
    <B>
      <C> txt </C>
      <C> txt </C>
    </B>
  </e>
</e>
```

Example tree with desired answer `0`:

```xml
<e>
  <A> txt </A>
  <e>
    <A> NO </A>
    <B>
      <C> txt </C>
      <C> txt </C>
    </B>
  </e>
</e>
```

The path should be relative to `//e/C`. I've tried:

- `//e/e[count(A = .//C)]` -- not valid XPath since we can only `count()` nodes, not logical conditions
- `//e/e[count(A[self::* = .//C])]` -- wrong. Only counts the `A` nodes, so gives 1, not 2, in the first case
- `//e/e[count(.//C[self::* = ancestor::*/preceding-sibling::A])]` -- wrong. Includes the `<A>` node which is an ancestor of the "inner" `<e>`, giving 1, which is incorrect.

The actual trees are more complicated, of course, so constructing a condition on `ancestor::*` will be hard -- any risk of matching ancestors of the "inner" `<e>` is likely to produce false positives.

Is there some syntax/function I'm missing that can help to count matching pairs like here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath gets the expected count based on the provided sample

```
count(//e/e//C[. = preceding::A[1]])
```

Could be read as: "count **C** nodes descendants of an **e** node that are equal to the first preceding **A** node"

Given this sample

```
<e>
  <A> txtNO </A>
  <e>
    <A> txt </A>
    <B>
      <C> txt </C>
      <C> txtNO </C>
      <C> txt </C>
    </B>
  </e>
</e>
```

Result

```
xmllint --xpath 'count(//e/e//C[. = preceding::A[1]])' tmp.xml
2
```

Testing the second preceding node with `count(//e/e//C[. = preceding::A[2]]` would returned `1` since `textNO` nodes would have been matched.

Comment: preceding::*[1] indeed looks promising! wouldn't have thought of that. let me give it a try.

Comment: Indeed it worked! It may need some fine-tuning for full generality but I think this is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

For best performance and accuracy I would use this XPath:

```
count(//C[text()= parent::B/preceding-sibling::A[1]/text()]
```

Having this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<e>
  <A> txt </A>
  <e>
    <A> txt </A>
    <B>
      <C> txt </C><!-- 1 -->
      <C> txt </C><!-- 1 -->
      <C> NO  </C><!-- 0 -->
    </B>
  </e>
  <e>
    <A> NO  </A>
    <B>
      <C> txt </C><!-- 0 -->
      <C> txt </C><!-- 0 -->
      <C> NO  </C><!-- 1 -->
    </B>
  </e>
</e>
```

Will give 3 as result

Comment: my examples are oversimplified -- preceding:: is needed because the level of parent:: can vary. If you're aware of a way to impose ancestor[at most n levels up] I'd be really interested to hear that